# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have created a spring boot web project using a 2.1.8 version of boot from https://start.spring.io/.
When I run the project, it throws the error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslator

Please help me out in resolving this issue.

**Pom.xml**

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Application starter class code:**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.mkcl.misServerMonitor")
public class MisServerMonitorApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MisServerMonitorApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding [`spring-dao`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-dao) dependency

Comment: @michalk, tried adding spring-dao but it throws error like:                            

The method's class, org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/avadhutp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-dao/2.0.6/spring-dao-2.0.6.jar!/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/avadhutp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-dao/2.0.6/spring-dao-2.0.6.jar

Comment: Check if the package name of the MisServerMonitorApplication class is the same with the groupId in pom.xml.